# Reading and writing from a file

Tags: c++

I need to make card catalog entries for a library system and will need a menu and save the card and read the card from a file. I'm just looking for help and not saving for anyone to do it just tips if you have any because I want ro learn and not just copy and paste.

I already finished the information they need to add but having a problem making them save and read from a file and choosing from the menu to add new entry, review entry.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

struct libary
{
    string title;
    string author;
    string ISBN_code;
    int page_count;
    int publish_year;
} s[10];

bool processMenu()
{
    int choice, spot;
    cout << "Main Menu" << endl;
    cout << "Select your options" << endl;
    cout << "1. Add a new entry to the system" << endl;
    cout << "2. Review an entry" << endl;
    cout << "3. Save entries to a file" << endl;
    cout << "4. Read entries from a file" << endl;

    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1:
            cout << "which spot do you want to add a entry to the system " << endl;
            cin >> spot;
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "which spot do you want to review to a file " << endl;
            cin >> spot;
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "Save entries to a file" << endl;
            ofstream myfile;
            myfile.open("file.txt");
            myfile << "this will show in the file";

            break;

        case 4:
            cout << "read entries from a file :" << endl;
            break;
        case 7:
            return 0;
    }
}
int main()
{

    while (!processMenu())
    {
        cout << "Sorry, that is not a valid choice." << endl;
        cout << "Please try again." << endl << endl << endl;
    }
    cout << " Enter information of each card catalog" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << " Enter title " << endl;
        cin >> s[i].title;

        cout << endl;

        cout << " Enter author " << endl;
        cin >> s[i].author;

        cout << endl;

        cout << " Enter Page count " << endl;
        cin >> s[i].page_count;

        cout << endl;

        cout << " Enter publish year " << endl;
        cin >> s[i].publish_year;

        cout << endl;

        cout << " Enter ISBN code, it should be 13 digits" << endl;
        cin >> s[i].ISBN_code;
        while (s[i].ISBN_code.length() != 13)
        {
            cout << " Please enter a ISBN code thats 13 digits" << endl;
            cin >> s[i].ISBN_code;
            cout << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }

    }

    cout << " Displaying Information" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << " title: " << s[i].title << endl;
        cout << " author: " << s[i].author << endl;
        cout << " page count: " << s[i].page_count << endl;
        cout << " publish year: " << s[i].publish_year << endl;
        cout << " ISBN code: " << s[i].ISBN_code << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It lets me pick a spot but won't add new entry nor review or save/read.

Comment: What does your `processMenu` function return when `choice` is not equal to `7`?

Comment: its suppose to be case 5 which it will return/ exit the program

Comment: I was making a note about recursive `processMenu` being a really bad idea, then noticed that the indentation was broken. Bad indentation causes problems.

Comment: Now that the indentation is sorted, it looks like most of the cases in `processMenu` do not `return` as advertised. This invokes undefined behaviour and will cause undefined porblems. See? It'a already affected my typingnnhg.

Comment: I have a c++ book and it's my first year learning c++ and. Yes I know there's no case 5. I had case 7 but I meant to put case 5 not case 7 and that's why I said it was supposed to return it. in this project, the menu should, add a new entry to the system, review an entry, save entries to a file or read entries from a file for part 2 
    (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            cout << endl;
            cout << " Enter title " << endl;
            cin >> s[i].title;

Comment: Rather than `case 7:` use `default:`. `default` will catch every number not specified in a `case`. It can't help you if the user types something that's not a number, though.  You need to guard against that.

Comment: Suggestion: don't add new code to code that's incorrect. Building on a shaky foundation generally leads to throwing out code latter when you find that it doesn't fit with the replacements for the broken pieces. Plus bugs gang up on you and protect one another.  They hide one another and all too often you will fix a bug and not realize it because the program still doesn't work thanks to another bug. Write a little bit of code. Test the program. Only proceed to writing more new code when the program functions exactly as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own type writable to a stream (`cout` or `ofstream`) and/or readable from a stream (`cin` or `ifstream`) just by overriding its output (`operator<<`) and/or input operator (`operator>>`).

```cpp
#include <fstream> // ifstream, ofstream
#include <iostream> // cin, cout
#include <string> // getline, string

using namespace std;

struct Card
{
    // Writing to the standard output ('cout').
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Card& card);
    // Reading from the standard input ('cin').
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, Card& card);
    // Writing to a file ('ofstream').
    friend ofstream& operator<<(ofstream& os, const Card& card);
    // Reading from a file ('ifstream).
    friend ifstream& operator>>(ifstream& is, Card& card);

    string title = "";
    string author = "";
    string isbn = "";
    int page_count = -1;
    int publish_year = -1;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Card& card)
{
    os << "Title: " << card.title << '\n'
       << "Author: " << card.author << '\n'
       << "ISBN: " << card.isbn << '\n'
       << "Page count: " << card.page_count << '\n'
       << "Publish year: " << card.publish_year << '\n';
    return os;
}

istream& operator>>(istream& is, Card& card)
{
    // 'getline' needs for the reading of strings because the title of a book or
    // its author's name may contain Space (' ') characters. 'cin' and
    // 'ifstream' separate input by every whitespace. So, if we want to allow
    // spaces in our fields we have to separate them by a special delimiter 
    // character. We use the Newline ('\n') character here to separate fields.
    // `page_count` and `publish_year` are numbers, they don't contain 
    // whitespaces, so they simply can be read with 'operator>>'.
    cout << "Title: ";
    std::getline(is, card.title);
    cout << "Author: ";
    std::getline(is, card.author);
    cout << "ISBN code: ";
    std::getline(is, card.isbn);
    cout << "Page count: ";
    is >> card.page_count;
    cout << "Publish year: ";
    is >> card.publish_year;
    return is;
}

// The next two functions is for files.
ofstream& operator<<(ofstream& os, const Card& card)
{
    os << card.title << '\n'
       << card.author << '\n'
       << card.isbn << '\n'
       << card.page_count << '\n'
       << card.publish_year << '\n';
    return os;
}

ifstream& operator>>(ifstream& is, Card& card)
{
    std::getline(is, card.title);
    std::getline(is, card.author);
    std::getline(is, card.isbn);
    is >> card.page_count;
    is >> card.publish_year;
    return is;
}

int main()
{
    Card card;

    // Read the informations of a card from the standard input.
    cin >> card;

    // Write the informations of a card to the standard output.
    cout << card;

    // Write the informations of a card to "file.txt".
    ofstream ofs("file.txt");
    ofs << card;
    ofs.close();

    // Read the informations of a card from "file.txt".
    ifstream ifs("file.txt");
    ifs >> card;
    ifs.close();

    return 0;
}
```

**Important:** For the sake of simplicity, I omitted error checking at the opening of a file and at the writing/reading of a stream. In your code you should do these.